# Keycloak with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, keycloak

I'm trying to integrate Keycloak with an existing web app that uses RequireJS. The web app has several entry points (index.html files) all based off of Vue app. I've got it working, but I'll have to update every index.html to include a `<script src="keycloak.js">` tag, and I'd prefer not to do that for the sake of maintainability and multiple developers adding new entry points. I'd like to import keycloak.js once using require.js in my app.js file, but I'm getting funky behavior when I do that. It appears that keycloak.js is not defined in a way that RequireJS can use it normally. The keycloak.js file I downloaded is from here: https://downloads.jboss.org/keycloak/10.0.2/adapters/keycloak-oidc/keycloak-js-adapter-dist-10.0.2.zip

Specifically, when I do this:

```
define(["keycloak"], function(Keycloak) {
  
  // Initialize keycloak
  var keycloak = new Keycloak(basePath + '/keycloak.json');
  keycloak.init({
    onLoad: 'check-sso', 
    silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: 'https://my.auth.url/auth/'
  }).success(function(authenticated) {
    alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
  }).error(function() {
    alert('failed to initialize');
  });
}
```

In the console I get:

```
TypeError: "keycloak.init is not a function"
```

I tried printing keycloak to the console after the "new" statement, and the object looks like this:

[image: Object after 'new' imported by RequireJS]

If I import keycloak.js using the `<script>` tag in my HTML, it looks like the object I would expect, and it has an init() function (and the rest of the code goes merrily on its way).

How can I use RequireJS to import keycloak.js the same way the `<script>` tag does?

EDIT: I tried just printing out Keycloak (without new-ing or using it in any way) when importing it through a `<script>` tag, and I got this object, which looks a lot different and has a Keycloak constructor:

[image: Object from script tag]

When I do the same thing after importing through RequireJS, I get this:

[image: Object from RequireJS]

Comment: I assume you have configured RequireJS appropriately. Like `paths: {keycloak: 'path/to/keycloak.js}`?

Comment: Yes. I have also verified that it is finding the file (via the network tab). Keycloak is defined, it just doesn't look the same as when I pull it in via a <script> tag.

Comment: Seems that file keycloaks.js is a bundle of script, so it defines multiple scripts. But I think it is possible to load via RequireJS by doing `require('path/to/keycloak.js', function () { define(['keycloak'], function (keycloak) { /*your code here */ }); );`